# LambdaInvokeAction Ends Up Doing Cloudformation Deploy

Tags: python, aws-cdk

I'm trying to invoke an existing lambda in my codepipeline using CDK. However, when i run `cdk deploy` instead of invoking a lambda, it will instead do Cloudformation Deploy, anyone know why is this?

This is my Stack

```
class ExistingLambdaStack(StackBase):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:

        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        invoke = cp_action.LambdaInvokeAction(
                action_name="Existing-lambda",
                lambda_=_lambda.Function.from_function_arn(
                    self,
                    "Existing-lambda",
                    "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:13245:function:Existing-Function",
                ),
                user_parameters={"bucket_key":"my_bucket"}
            ),
```

Then i added the stack in my stage

```
class ExistingLambdaPipelineStage(Stage):
    def __init__(
        self,
        scope: Construct,
        id: str,
        **kwargs
    ):

        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        ExistingLambdaStack(
            self, "Existing-lambda"
        )
```

Then i added it in my pipeline

```
        pipeline = ...

        existing_lambda_pipeline_stage = ExistingLambdaPipelineStage(
            self, "lambda-pipeline")

        pipeline.add_stage(existing_lambda_pipeline_stage)
```

Comment: The `Pipeline > Stage > Stack > Lambda Invoke Action` construct hierarchy is not right.  What pipeline construct are you using?